# Linking extern variables using multiple library in C

Tags: c, shared-libraries, extern

In my project, I have two libraries and one program.

- `Lib1.c` and `Lib1.h` are two files of first library(`Lib1.so`).
- `Lib2.c` and `Lib2.h` are two files of second library(`Lib2.so`).
- `prog.c` is the main file of program(`prog`).

The program(`prog`) is linked only to the second library(`Lib2.so`) and the second library(`Lib2.so`) is linked to the first library(`Lib1.so`).

In `Lib1.c`, I have a declaration of global variable (`int var = 0;`) and in `Lib1.h`, I have a declaration (`extern int var;`).

In `Lib2.h`, I have a declaration (`extern int var;`) in order to use `var` variable in main program.

In `main()` function, I include the `Lib2.h` in `prog.c` file and I have a declaration (`var = 5;`)

Lib1.c :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Lib1.h"

int var = 0;

int funct(void)
{
    printf("hello world \n");
    return 0;
}
```

Lib1.h :

```
extern int var;

int funct(void);
```

Lib2.c :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Lib2.h"

int funct2(void)
{
    printf("Library 2 \n");
    funct();
    return 0;
}
```

Lib2.h :

```
#include "Lib1.h"

extern int var;

int funct2(void);
```

prog.c :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Lib2.h"

int main() 
{
    var = 5;
    printf("===>var=%d\n", var);
    funct2();
    return 1;
}
```

Commands :

```
gcc -c -Wall -Werror -fpic Lib1.c 
gcc -shared -o Lib1.so Lib1.o
gcc -c -Wall -Werror -fpic Lib2.c
gcc -shared -o Lib2.so Lib2.o -ldl /home/test/Lib1.so
gcc prog.c -o prog -ldl /home/test/Lib2.so
```

When I try to compile the program(`prog.c`), I get an error in the link step as below.

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccKaq16a.o: undefined reference to symbol 'var'
/home/test/Lib1.so: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
```

Is there a way to use var variable in the main function when its defined in the first library?

Comment: I think from what you described it should work, so there is something you did not describe and the error is somewhere else. Please post the exact error message. Please post the commands you used to compile and link the programs, for example in a ready-to-use makefile format. Please post the contents of the files, rather then "describing" what they contain. Post their content. Use [code formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)Please create an [MCVE]. Note, shared libraries are not, like, "transitive" -  you need to link `prog` against `Lib1.so`.

Comment: @KamilCuk I have updated the question with the necessary codes and commands.

Answer (score 0):

You link your program against Lib2 but not Lib1.  You need to add that as well.  You also don't need to explicitly link Lib1 when you create Lib2

```
gcc -c -Wall -Werror -fpic Lib1.c 
gcc -shared -o Lib1.so Lib1.o
gcc -c -Wall -Werror -fpic Lib2.c
gcc -shared -o Lib2.so Lib2.o
gcc prog.c -o prog /home/test/Lib2.so /home/test/Lib1.so
```

Comment: is there a method to link my prog only to Lib2.so?